# Add 1 day to date field when using between in SQL Query in DB2

Tags: db2, birt

I would like to know how to add 1 day to the date field when using between. For example user will enter the date as 01-Jul-2019 to 31-Jul-2019 but it appears as below

`" between " + MXReportSqlFormat.getStartDayTimestampFunction(params["gprmStartDate"]) 
 " and " + MXReportSqlFormat.getEndDayTimestampFunction(params["gprmEndDate"])`
it appears as below

```
and meter.readingdate  between { ts '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000' } and { ts '2019-07-30 23:59:59.998' }
```

I have tried to use + 1 day however it doesn't work. Not sure how to add 1 day when using BETWEEN in the SQL query

Comment: Check out the birt date functions? example BirtDateTime.addDay ?

Comment: First off, [don't use `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - you should be using an exclusive upper-bound (`<`): timestamps in DB2 have 7 fractional digits, so you're off.  I'm not too sure what you're doing, but if you're concatenating the query you should be switching to some form of a paramterized query - and at that point you could get the next day in your application code.  What does "it doesn't work" mean?  What doesn't work?  Do you get an error?  Which error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the 1 day in SQL. E.g.

```
values TIMESTAMP( { ts '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000' } ) + 1 DAY
```

returns

```
1
---------------------
2019-01-02 00:00:00.0
```

when using JDBC